# Callback on animation end in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, callback

Using Unity 4.6 and 2D stuff with animations.

I am animating a GameObject and have a few transitions to go back and forth between states performing animations. The animations are generally non-repeating. How can I attach a callback to a script function to be called when an animation ends?

Answer (score 0):

I found something call Animation Event. I can easily call a function with this at specified time in the animation interval. It would probably work in many cases...

The problem is that this time round I have one animation that is used twice, once to go from state A to state B, and then the same animation going from B back to A using time set to -1. The animation "end" callback would be called at the end of a positive animation, but called at the beginning of a negative animation. Feels like it gets too complicated to make any sense out of that and a cleaner solution would be appropriate.

Comment: rather than have the callback at the "end" of the transition to a given state could you not have it at the "start" of the animation in that state? or does it loop?

Comment: The animation is used in two ways, like I said. 1: from start to finish, 2: from finish to start (as I said, just set time to -1 to achieve this). No matter where I put the animation event, it will be called in both animations and without some extra tricks I wouldn't know which animation was called.

Comment: ok, i think we're using different outlooks on the animator state machine... but no matter.  Could you check `if(Animator.speed = -1){...}` in the event or something similar? failing that I would perhaps have the animation imported twice, once for forwards with the event and once for backwards without.

Comment: Yes that. Or I implemented a lambda property in the animated game object. Before I animate the object, I fill the lambda with some function I want executed. When the animation hits the event, it calls a function on the game object (the script, really) and if there's a lambda function there, it copies it, deletes it, then uses it. Maybe breaks in the future. That's the kind of trick I did... This all would be easier with some staple animation callbacks... that all other rendering engines have :-) Now I agree that running an animation backwards could be an acceptable exception.